# Share memory region mapping between two binaries

Tags: c, gcc, linker, stm32, ld

The way you write a program for a dual-core MCU is that each core executes its own separate binary.

I want to create a shared static variables in common source file for which static allocations will be managed by the linker, so that the addresses of individual variables are the same from the perspective of the two cores.  Is there any way to achieve this without explicity assigning addresses?

Already I created overlapping memory region in linker scripts for both cores,

```
/* Specify the memory areas */
MEMORY
{
    RAM4_D3_NO_CACHE (xrw)   : ORIGIN = 0x38000000, LENGTH = 8K
}
```

```
    .ram4_d3_non_cachable :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    _sram4_d3_non_cachable = .;
    *(.ram4_d3_non_cachable)
    *(.ram4_d3_non_cachable*)

    . = ALIGN(8);
    _eram4_d3_non_cachable = .;
  } >RAM4_D3_NO_CACHE AT> FLASH
```

but then location of each symbol is different (as expected from two independent linking processes per binary):

```
  .ram4_d3_non_cachable                                                                              
                 0x0000000038001fc0       0x9c build/ic_queue.o                                      
                 0x0000000038001fc0                isInit                                            
                 0x0000000038001fc4                m4ToM7                                            
                 0x0000000038001fd0                descriptors                                
                 0x0000000038002050                m7ToM4                                            
  *(.ram4_d3_non_cachable*)
```

```
  .ram4_d3_non_cachable                                                                             
                 0x0000000038001fc0       0x9c build/ic_queue.o                                      
                 0x0000000038001fc0                m4ToM7                                            
                 0x0000000038001fcc                m7ToM4                                            
                 0x0000000038001fd8                descriptors                                
                 0x0000000038002058                isInit                                            
  *(.ram4_d3_non_cachable*)
```

Comment: What MCU and what OS? What you're describing is "threads" (vs processes). They share memory space. (e.g.) Under linux, this is pthreads. FreeRtos also shares memory. You probably want to use those rather than trying to get the linker to do this. For separate programs, they can use (e.g. `mmap` or SysV `shmget` to get a shared area). What is some example code that illustrates your problem?

Comment: MCU is STM32H745. I have freeRTOS on M7 core, but M4 core are bare-metal. Do you know where I can find implementation of such sharable memory in freeRTOS code?